# React native automatic update from store

Tags: react-native, auto-update

Hi guys I need my react native app to update it self automatically (with user consent) when new version is published to the store (both android and ios)
I need the app to download the apk or ipa and complete the update process, not using CODE PUSH or OTA,
is it possible?

Comment: Do you want it to do that over the PlayStore/AppStore? If yes I assume it is not possible. The stores ask for the user's consent before they update (unless configured otherwise) which is how it should be. Anyhow, at least on android you, as a user, may grant special permission to an app to install other apks. So you could download the app internally and re-install it this way. The user still needs to press install though. So generally, no it's not possible and should not be possible. But you can easily fetch datasets from a server and update those on the fly.

Comment: yes I want to do it over the store, but with user consent, I can show alert to get user agreement, then when he press update, complete the process, so forget about (silently ), is it possible to complete the update process via PlayStore/AppStore automatically after user consent?

Comment: Only if the user enables auto-update. And I do not know if you can prompt for that. If you are simply concerned that the user might get out of date, you could have some before app screen that verifies the version (against a server) and doesn't boot the app unless it is newer than X versions (I personally dislike this though).

Comment: Some of my application users were unable to complete the update process due to lack experience of using mobile and managing applications, so my main goal is to help those users by automating the update process

Comment: so if the user enable 'auto-update' option in PlayStore/AppStore settings, will my app update automatically? theres nothing needed to do in development phase?

Comment: Yup if enabled it automatically updates it. Not as soon as the update comes out, but you can expect all users that have enabled it to have the new update within one to three days.

Comment: thanx a lot for your time and answers.

Comment: are you the device admin? if yes, you are looking for MDM services.

Comment: @Horst no I'm not, it can be installed by any customer

Comment: @OlfatGhazali Then I am afraid asking users to turn on auto-update is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

The app itself can't do that.

The closest thing you can do is:

1. Verify app version against the version on the server (if you have a back end).
2. Present a button to the user which will open the app store off your platform directly at your app's page, using deep linking.

You will have to keep server and deployed app versions in sync.